# set compression level with nice and tar

Tags: tar, gzip

How to set compression level here?

```
nice -n 19 tar -czf $out $in
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nice` won't do anything to the level of compression. It will only affect the scheduling of the process by the kernel. All commands below may be prefixed with `nice` to run them at a different "nice"-level, it will not influence the level of compression, only the time taken to perform the action (if the system is under heavy load).

If you're using GNU `tar` then the compression program may be set with either the `-I` or the `--use-compress-program` options:

```
$ tar -I "gzip --best" -c -f archive.tar.gz dir
```

or

```
$ tar --use-compress-program="gzip --best" -c -f archive.tar.gz dir
```

Note that the `-z` option should not be used if you set the compression program explicitly.

The GNU `tar` manual states that the program used must support an `-d` option for decompression (if you use these options for decompressing a compressed archive), which `gzip` does.

With BSD `tar` it's not possible to specify the level of compression in a similar way, as far as I have seen.

The other way to achieve this is obviously to create an un-compressed archive and then compress that in the way one wants:

```
$ tar -c -f archive.tar dir
$ gzip --best archive.tar
```

or

```
$ tar -c dir | gzip --best -o archive.tar.gz
```

Yet *another* way is to set the `GZIP` environment variable to the flags that you'd like to pass to `gzip`:

```
$ export GZIP='--best'
$ tar -c -z -f archive.tar.gz dir
```

Except for the use of `-I` and `--use-compress-program`, the last few alternatives work with both GNU and BSD `tar`.

Comment: `tar -c dir | gzip --best > archive.tar.gz`

Comment: yes, but I need to use `nice`

Comment: @clarkk You may use `nice`. `nice` have no impact on the creation of the archive or on the compression, it just changes the scheduling of the `tar`/`gzip` process. My answer deals with setting the level of compression. Just prefix the commands with `nice` (as you did in your question) and it will work nicely.